# Graph Theory Proof- Given a graph has 6 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

**Question:**  Give an example of a graph that has $6$ vertices with degrees of 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2. How many edges does your graph have? Can you argue that any graph with these properties would have the same number of edges?

**My Thought Process :** I am pretty sure there are $8$ edges. Usually these graph theory problems use induction but I am not sure how I would induction since if I removed or added a node it would change the properties of the graph. Could I use a proof by contradiction?

[image]

Comment: Did you first give an example of a graph? Did you count its edges?

Comment: Yep I created, a graph with a UML program on another computer and counted the edges and I got 8.

Comment: @shane I would be very interested in seeing that graph!

Comment: @shane In that case did you count the degrees of its vertices?

Comment: I added an image and counted everything.

Comment: @shane count the number of edges again ...

Comment: The linked graph has more than $8$ edges

Comment: thanks I see that now I must have miscounted but I will be interested in more of solving the proof.

Comment: @shane See my Answer ... let me know if that still doesn't make it clear

Comment: it does thanks, I think I was over complicating this problem in my head thinking about it in a series of steps.

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Every edge connects 2 vertices, so the sum of all the degrees for all vertices goes up by two for every edge (note that an edge from a vertex to itself increases its degree by 2, so it still works there). In sum: the total of all the degrees will always be twice the number of edges.

Comment: ok thanks, I miscounted the edges and I see there are 18 total degrees and 9 edges so using that proof I could show that there are sumOfDegrees/2 = number of edges.

Comment: @shane Right .. so that answers the second half of your question: *any* graph with those degrees will have to have 9 edges. That's why I asked for your picture, since I knew there had to be something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [handshake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), we can calculate the edges to be $9$. This is because the total number of degrees is equal to $2$ times the number of edges. A graph with a sum of $18$ total degrees must always have $9$ edges.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).